# comparing two request attributes in jstl tag

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I have two request attributes in one JSP file(designation and employee). I want to compare their fields in  tag. Below is my code

```
<c:if test="${designation.id eq employee.designation}">selected</c:if>.
```

But with above code, it's not showing selected value in the dropdown list on UI side.
I have also tried test="${designation.id} eq ${employee.designation}" but won't succeded.

Comment: It simply means they're not equal. Debug, see what each value is. If their type matches, etc.

Comment: No buddy. They are equal in value and type as well.

Comment: Then, if the JSTL is properly installed, selected should be printed. Do you look at the right place? Have you looked at the generated HTML? How did you test that?

Comment: Actually, I am using "selected" to drop-down list to select designation by default. And designation is not selected by default.

Comment: That's irrelevant. Look at the generated HTML. Is the `selected`text there is the only thing that matters.

Comment: But there is no "selected" text in generated HTML.

Comment: Then they're not equal. We can only make guesses if you don't post any more code, don't post the output, don't tell how you checked the values and types of the two values, don't post the output of that check, etc.

Comment: @JBNizet. It's working. You were right about they're not equal. It's actually my project build issue and I am assuming that all are fine. Thanks for help and time.